# Reference previous value in v-for in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a grid created with vue.js, but I've having difficulty getting the right index for the values after a keyword filter is applied.

```
<tbody v-for="
      entry in data
    | filterBy filterKey
    | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <tr v-if="$index == 0 || ($index > 0 && entry['value'] != data[$index-1]['value'])">
            <td class="Header" colspan="3">
                    VALUE: @{{{entry["value"]}}}
            </td>
        </tr>
 ...
```

In this case, {{$index}} gives 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. However, when a filter is applied, only parts of the data are visible on-screen. (i.e. only the entries at indexes 6 and 8) Unfortunately, $index is still incrementing by 1 starting at 0, making it impossible to reference the previous entry. What is the correct way to reference the previous entry?

(I want to check if a certain part of the entry is different than the one above it, and if it is, create a new header. I have it working except for when a keyword filter is applied)

Comment: so when you say "previous" you mean "previous in  `this.data`", instead of the items being filtered and shown?

Comment: For example, out of 8 entries only 2 show up with a filter. In that case, this for loop happens twice. Although the 2 items shown are actually numbers 6 and 8, the index variable only has 0 and 1. Within the 2nd iteratuon of the loop,  I need to find a way to reference the 'entry' in the previous iteration of the loop. So *not* the previous in the data variable, the previous in the data being filtered and shown is what I want.

Comment: I see, for that you need to keep an array `prev` and update `previous` values whenever value changes.
Best way to do it is to warp `data | filter | sort` in a computed property and `$watch` the *computed property* for changes reference for [$watch](https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-watch) and [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html). I will try to make a jsfiddle for clarity.

Comment: That sounds great! I'll try it out, but I'm new to vue.js so  a jsfiddle would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a custom filter to populate a filtered array that can utilize the new indexes:

add another prop for the data filtered:

```
    data: Array,
    dataFiltered: Array,
```

Then add a custom filter that doesn't actually filter anything, but stores the filtered array:

```
    Vue.filter('populateFilteredData', function (filteredArray, input) {
        this.dataFiltered = filteredArray;
        return filteredArray;
    });
```

make sure this filter is used *AFTER* all other filters and sorts:

```
 <tbody v-for="
      entry in data
    | filterBy filterKey
    | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]
    | populateFilteredData
     ">
```

then the filtered array can be used to access information from previous iterations of the v-for loop like this:

```
{{{ dataFiltered[$index-1] }}}
```

That took quite some time to figure out and was really counter-intuitive. If anyone knows a better way (that is still concise and simple) to accomplish the same thing, please post your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jsfiddle as I said

https://jsfiddle.net/sg4jtzzw/

The gist of it is that

A computed property is added which encapsulates filtering and sorting on `this.data`

```
computed:{
    special: function(){
        var key= this.filt;
        return this.data.filter(function(row){ 
            return row.indexOf(key)!= -1;   
        }).sort(); 
    }
}
```

In ready function, we initialize a `$watch` to update `prev` according to value of `special`

```
ready: function(){
  var self = this;
  self.prev= [];
  this.$watch('special',function(newVal, oldVal){
    self.prev = oldVal;  
  });
}
```

Html portion is quite simplified and compact

```
<div v-for="item in special">
  <span v-if=" previousList(item)== true"> Old </span>
  {{ item }}
 </div>
```

Note: both `filter()` and `sort()` are js functions, not vue functions, and are case-sensitive. The code would be less verbose if I were to use vue filters, but I don't how to. As using built-in filters is not recommended approach, I don't advise using them either

To know about recommended approach on filters, you can read the [discussion on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2756)

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd mention this, in case it could assist anyone. Don't forget the power of just specifically referencing the array you're iterating through by its index and manually grabbing values in if statements, rather than writing contrived loop methods. For example:

```
<div class="schedule-data-container" :class="{roundShift: i==0 || schedules[i-(i>1 ? 1 : 0)].round < s.round}" v-for="(s,i) in schedules" :key="i">
    <div class="roundNumber" v-if="i==0 || schedules[i-(i>1 ? 1 : 0)].round < s.round">
        Round {{ s.round }}
    </div>
</div>
```